# Rate this app funtionlity

Tags: ios, ios4, app-store

i am trying to provide the rate this app functionality into my application hence i added the below code

```
- (void)gotoReviews
//------------------
{
  NSString *str = @"itms-apps://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa";
  str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?", str]; 
  str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@type=Purple+Software&id=", str];


  str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@APPid", str]; 

  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:str]];

}
```

str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@APPid", str];  here i have to mention my app id.i see the appid into the provisioning portal as following 546F5QMTE4.com.XXXX.XXXX into the APp id section.

Is that the "546F5QMTE4" string need to placed? am i right is that correct id?

please let me know

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in many ways:

1. Direct approach:

   ```
   #define APP_ID XXXXX //id from iTunesConnect
   NSString *reviewURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"itms-apps://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?type=Purple+Software&id=%d",APP_ID];

   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:reviewURL]];
   ```
2. Try with Appirator in app delegate:

   ```
    [Appirater setAppId:@"552035781"];
    [Appirater setDaysUntilPrompt:1];
    [Appirater setUsesUntilPrompt:10];
    [Appirater setSignificantEventsUntilPrompt:-1];
    [Appirater setTimeBeforeReminding:2];
    [Appirater setDebug:YES];
   ```

You can get source: [Here](https://github.com/arashpayan/appirater). 
Add Appirater.h and Appirater.m to your project.

For more information about integration: [Here](http://arashpayan.com/blog/2009/09/07/presenting-appirater/)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

:)
No, it is not that number. You have to go to the iTunesConnect -> Manage Your Apps, choose your app, then look under "App Information" for Apple ID (digits only).

Of course be sure that you have actually a record for your app. If not, just make it (Add New App button).

Answer (score 1):

**iRate** is best https://github.com/nicklockwood/iRate

The one that I use and works wonders on iOS 5+ (also available for Mac OS X, but this answer is focused on the iOS portion) and up on all devices (iPad, iPhone, iPod Touch) is iRate.

It uses a uialertview and storekit to ask the user for a rating (or to remind them later). Everything is customizable, from the name of the Cancel Button Title to the Interval at which it reminds the user.

By default, iRate automatically opens when certain requirements are met (ex. app launched X number of times, user passed X number of levels), but you can also use a variety of methods and your own logic (with the help of iRate methods) to manually display an iRate popup.

**Setup**

To install, 
just drag the header (.H) file the implementation (.M) file, and the iRate Bundle (for localization) into your project.

Import the header in your AppDelegate: **#import "iRate.h"**

Add the StoreKit Framework to your project - More on StoreKit from Apple Documentation

Add the following method to your app delegate: **+ (void)initialize**

The properties can be set in the initialize method, however none of them are required (iRate can automatically find all of this information).

Answer (score 0):

No, it isn't. It's rather a numeric ID with a few digits, something like this:

```
http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?id=389801252&pageNumber=0&sortOrdering=1&type=Purple+Software
```

This will only be live when your application has been approved by Apple **and** it's already on the AppStore (in case of an intentionally delayed launch).

**Furthermore,** the way you're composing that poor URL string is **simply horrible.** Don't abuse format strings! You have a constant string here, so you don't even need any call to `+ [NSString stringWithFormat:]`. Even if you wanted to alter the app ID, you could do that using one single formatting statement:

```
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?id=%@&pageNumber=0&sortOrdering=1&type=Purple+Software", appID];
```